# How to create a file under specific workspace in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

[image]I'm trying to create a file under the folder present in the workspace.
When I right-click the folder, I do not get a menu item to create a new file under this directory.

In Sublime text application we get the option to create a file under a specific directory in the workspace by right click on the folder > "Create a new file".

Answer (score 0):

#### Menu allows you to open Windows Explorer, create blank items there and return.

1. In your screenshot, you show menu option **Explorer here**. Select it.
2. In Windows Explorer, create the documents and folders you need.

   2.1. Right-click the blank space in the area where files are shown.

   2.2. From context menu, select **New** > **Text Document**  (or other document type you need).

   2.3. Name the document and finish by pressing **Enter**.
3. Switch back to Notepad++ and the new documents are now present at the bottom of the list. (The list was refreshed automatically.)

Comment: Is there not a way to do this natively in the workspace vs using Windows explorer?

Comment: @MBasith – I added an [additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392006/2392157) for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a file without leaving Notepad++

Ensure that you have selected menu > Settings > Prefences > Default Directory > Follow Current Document. If this is set, just do the following:

1. Switch N++ to any open document from desired workspace folder.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
3. Type file name of your new file and press Save button.

Done.

No explicit way of creating new files is stated in [manual to *Workspace as Folder* feature](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/session/#folder-as-workspace).